# Javascript encodeURIComponent issue on redirection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, encodeuricomponent

I've a search box works with jquery and php, when you type something in to this search box jquery prepares a query and redirects location. Preparing query part works good but redirection part has a problem with the encoded query. Page automatically decodes the encoded query before redirection.

If you type "test1 test2 test3" in to search box, it successfully encodes query to test1%20test2%20test3 with encodeURIComponent().

Now page will redirect itself to result.php+query. My problem here is page goes to result.php?q=test1 test2 test3 instead of result.php?q=test1%20test2%20test3.

here are codes

```
 if($("#searchbox").val() != "")
 {
    var mq1 = encodeURIComponent($("#searchbox").val());
    var query = "q="+mq1;

 }

 alert(query);
 if(query!="")
 location = "result.php?"+query;
```

alert result is q=test1%20test2%20test3 but it goes result.php?q=test1 test2 test3

edit: If i use encodeURIComponent function with redirection codes it works good.

```
 alert(query);
 if(query!="")
 location = "result.php?"+encodeURIComponentquery);
```

theese codes are working but it encodes q= part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, why not just write this:

```
if ($("#searchbox").val()) {
    location = 'result.php?' + $.param({
        q: $("#searchbox").val()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it's just the broswer is showing `test1 test2 test3` in the address bar, but the server gets the correct value. You can check that by a browser dev tools like firebug, or even check that in the server.

Comment: I change codes a bit to test this. Editing question now. See the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change it to `result.php?q=+encodeURIComponent(query)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of what you've written - it waits for the enter key to be hit after typing in your query (as I wasn't sure of the context of your code, whether it lies within a submit method for the form):

```
$('#searchbox').keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13 && $(this) {
       $(this).blur();
       var mq1 = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
       var query = "q="+mq1;
       window.location = "result.php?"+ query;
   }
});
```

Using this, it creates the following URL:

```
result.php?q=multiple%20words%20in%20the%20url%20work%20fine
```

​I think your code was almost there, but the logic surrounding the IF statement was causing issues.